# Adding Datetimes in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I am wondering if anyone can suggest solutions for adding together datetimes in mysql?

I have a scheduler datetime, and want to add another datetime which specifies a period like
'2012-03-23 10:00:00' + '0000-00-00 01:01:01'
Should of course produce '2012-03-23 11:01:01'.

MySQL doesn't seem to like doing this with any of the DATE_ADD/ADDDATE variants.

Hope there are some solutions for this.

Comment: What is the datatype of the second "datetime"? '0000-00-00 01:01:01' is not a datetime that can be stored in the database since month 0/day 0 does not exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visit
[mysql addDate](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_adddate)

The syntax is:

> mysql> SELECT ADDTIME('2007-12-31 23:59:59.999999', '1 1:1:1.000002');
>
> ```
>    -> '2008-01-02 01:01:01.000001'
> ```
>
> mysql> SELECT ADDTIME('01:00:00.999999', '02:00:00.999998');
>
> ```
>    -> '03:00:01.999997'
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
DATE_ADD(DATE_ADD(DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 HOUR), INTERVAL 1 MINUTE), INTERVAL 1 SECOND)
```

Works for me...